# ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException is thrown despite the array index being well within bounds

Tags: audio, processing

Alright,
This error first came up while using a for to load a bunch of songs I'd listed the titles of in a separate array, as shown below.
It is noteworthy that I'd run this sketch on an outdated version of the sound library, and that same line gave me an error the likes of "Gave up looking for a valid MPEG header after 65536 bytes of junk". If I only loaded one song, said error did not show up. Any more than that, and it did.
However, now that I updated the sound library, it gives me the ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception: 3.
Which is not only odd because in the array I'm using the maximum index allowed should be 7 (as its length is 8), but also because I use the ArrayIndex 1. See below.

My attempts to get rid of (or at least isolate) the error can be seen in the code below.
If it can be of any use, I'm using Processing 3.5, latest update of the Sound library, and OS X 10.9.5 (spare your mockery).

```
String[] titles={"Small Bump", "This", "I See Fire", "The City ", "The City", "Cake By The Ocean", "Never Gonna Give You Up", "Innamoratissimo"};
SoundFile[] songs= new SoundFile[titles.length];
int i=0;  
void setup(){  
  //for (int i=0; i<songs.length; i++) songs[i]=new SoundFile(this,titles[i]+".mp3");
  //This one gave me a fault
  //for (int i=0; i<1; i++) songs[i]=new SoundFile(this,titles[i]+".mp3");
  //This one ran ok
  //for (int i=0; i<2; i++) songs[i]=new SoundFile(this,titles[i]+".mp3");
  //This one threw a fit again
  //So I decided to list them manually to make sure the for wasn't doing funky stuff
  songs[0]=new SoundFile(this,"Small Bump.mp3");
  songs[1]=new SoundFile(this,"This.mp3");  //This is the line causing mayhem. See how the ArrayIndex is neither out of bounds nor 3?
}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [OutOfBoundsException in Processing (Sound library)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53950278/outofboundsexception-in-processing-sound-library)

Comment: @DWuest Sorry, I looked at a lot of possible duplicates, but wasn't lucky enough to stumble upon that one. If I may though, what causes the SoundFile library to throw such a fit?

Comment: No problem, it happens to the best of us! This I cannot tell you as I don't have time for debugging a library I rarely work with :D All I know is that it is just a bug which might get fixed in the future. However, it might be possible that it will never be fixed. But for now, just use the library I recommended in my answer of the question yours is a duplicate of. Happy coding!

Comment: can I know the content of your data folder so its easier to debug with you?

Comment: @DWuest Thank you, will try! I'll have to learn a whole new syntax, but it's not like that ever stopped anyone, right? (mild cursing may have occurred, though.)

Comment: @YOUSFIMohamedWalid it's all in this link:
https://www.dropbox.com/sh/di7mwit0w2l4513/AABipGDAdoKx277f8Hg_ZfhDa?dl=0